# Substituir valor por indice en array en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito dibujar un tablero en terminal, ya tengo el tablero pero necesito substituir la columna 3 y 7 por "*" también las rows pero de momento las columnas: Aquí el código

```
def draw_board(row,cols):

matrix = [[y for y in range(row)] for x in range(cols)]


for format in range(len(matrix)):

    print(matrix[format])

return format
```

Y el array:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nota: esta repuesta explica que hacer si quieres reemplazar valores luego de crear la "matriz".

#### alterando columnas

Teniendo en cuenta que cada item de la lista es una fila, para acceder a una "celda" especifica puedes usar slicing. Por ejemplo `matrix[0][0]` te devolverá la celda cuya fila es 0 y cuya columna es 0.

Sabiendo esto puedes usar la asignación para darle un nuevo valor a una posición de la lista. Ejemplo: `fila[0][0] = "*"`.
Con un bucle for que vaya recorriendo cada fila, puedes acceder a la celda que coincide con cada fila en una columna especifica:

```
for row in range(len(matrix)):
    matrix[row][3] = "*"
    matrix[row][7] = "*"
```

#### alterando filas

Usando el concepto de más arriba puedes acceder celda por celda y modificar asi la fila:

```
for row in (3, 5):
    for col in range(len(matrix[row])):
        matrix[row][col] = "*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes sustituirlo a la hora de generar la matriz.

En caso de que busques que sea por número de columna comprueba que `y + 1` no es ni 3 ni 7:

```
matrix = [[y if (y + 1) not in (3, 7) else '*' for y in range(row)] for x in range(cols)]
```

Si es por el valor de la columna simplemente comprueba con y:

```
matrix = [[y if y not in (3, 7) else '*' for y in range(row)] for x in range(cols)]
```

---

Puedes hacer lo mismo con las filas pero comparando el valor de `x`(o de `x + 1`):

```
matrix = [[y if y not in (3, 7) and x not in (3, 7) else '*' for y in range(row)] for x in range(cols)]
```